# Atomicity of a INSERT SELECT UNION ALL in Sql Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

We recently upgraded to SQL Server 2016 and we have started to see an error we never saw before.

The error could not be related at all to the upgrade, but I guess its worth mention it.

Our scenario is the following (shown with a way simpler queries):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TestTable

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable
(
    AsAt DATETIME,
    Key1 INT,
    Key2 INT
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ixc_TestTable ON dbo.TestTable (AsAt) 
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixu_TestTable ON dbo.TestTable (AsAt, Key1, Key2) 
GO




DELETE FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE Key1 = 1 AND AsAt = '20180131'

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
        ( AsAt, Key1, Key2 )
VALUES
        ( '20180131',
            1, -- Key1 - int
            3  -- Key2 - int
            )

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
        ( AsAt, Key1, Key2 )
SELECT
    AsAt,
    Key1,
    130
FROM
    dbo.TestTable AS tt
UNION ALL
SELECT
    AsAt,
    Key1,
    129
FROM
    dbo.TestTable AS tt
```

Sadly this small example doesn't fail

In the real world scenario the first `INSERT` is inserting a few thousands records, and both `SELECT` in the `UNION ALL` involve multiple `JOINS` but they key thing is that they `SELECT` from the table we are inserting in.

What we see, is that in some cases the `IXU` constraint fails with a duplicate being tried to be inserted for the `Key2 = 129`.

If we keep running the query we get some runs where it runs successfully and some where it fails.

This makes us think that the problem is that the first `SELECT` is being inserted and then `SELECTED` by the second insert, causing the duplicates.

There are two fixes that looks like get the query working fine every time:

- Adding a `WHERE Key2 <> 130` in the second `SELECT`
- `SELECT` the `UNION ALL` into a `#temp` table and then `INSERT` the results in the target table

We would have thought that the `SELECT UNION ALL` part of the `INSERT` should be executed atomically and then the results `INSERT` in the table. Are we wrong thinking that?

ie. The second select of the UNION ALL won't see the records inserted in the first SELECT.

Extra information:

- Our isolation level is `READ COMMITED`
- The stored procedure running the query runs inside a `TRANSACTION`
- Adding a `MAXDOP 1` to the query doesn't change anything
- The execution plan of a failed run only shows one `INSERT` node
- We recently added some `COLUMN STORE` indexes to the tables involved

**Update**: we have been trying to query without the Column Store indexes and although they are slower they don't fail. When we put the column store indexes back in again we get the error in a reasonable number of iterations (<200)

Comment: Of cause you cannot insert it, when you already inserted it once and you have unique index on.

Comment: @plaidDK we insert three different records. Two of them based on the first one. That should be ok as the Key2 field of each of them is different

Comment: In your procedure you also start with an empty table? Are you really, *really* sure the duplicate record isn't inserted in the first insert? (I'm sure you've checked, but it never hurts to double, triple or even quadruple check).

Comment: When you say this  `SELECT UNION ALL part of the INSERT should be executed atomically and then the results INSERT in the table` did you meant that the insert of this statement should not fail irrespective of other statements

Comment: @HoneyBadger no, the table is not empty, keep data for previous AsAt dates and also it could have for the current run, but the data is deleted as in the example. The key thing is the two fixes we know are working, plus the duplicates always is for Key2 = 129, which is only inserted on that SELECT

Comment: @TheGameiswar, no I meant that the second select on the UNION ALL shouldn't see the records inserted by the first SELECT

Comment: Union all will work as single select ,output of union all will be inserted  as a single operation,Also  don't you think this  `INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
        ( AsAt, Key1, Key2 )
VALUES
        ( '20180131',
            1, -- Key1 - int
            3  -- Key2 - int
            )` might have inserted some keys(130,29) which may cause duplicates

Comment: I would first reproduce and isolate the issue on a copy of the database, ideally on a development server.  Then you can simplify the repro and see if it is fixed by a later update of SQL 2016.

Comment: Do you actually know the result of the `UNION ALL` is guaranteed to produce unique records under every possible execution? `UNION` without `ALL` performs an implicit `DISTINCT`. The operation logically proceeds as follows: `SELECT` the first set of rows, `SELECT` the second, concatenate the results, `INSERT` the resulting row set. Note that there is no "ordering" where the rows of the first `SELECT` are inserted "first". They will actually be inserted however the engine pleases.

Comment: Note also that `COMMITTED` still allows non-repeatable reads, which matters if your source queries actually involve the destination table in some complicated join to select rows that "aren't there yet" and other queries are happening concurrently. The columnstore index may be a red herring, or it may also expose a genuine bug in the engine -- but you should make very sure your query can't possibly be at fault itself.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft we have reproduced it in isolation, and I think we are opening a support ticket.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, the select itself doesn't produce duplicates, if you insert into a temp table first and then insert whatever is there in the final table no duplicates are created. I know the column store could be just a red herrin, its making the query be much faster so that maybe making the error more likely to occur. Re the isolation level I will double check that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping the UNION ALL syntax, this may eliminate whatever execution plan oddity being observed. I cannot replicate, so I cannot know for certain. But it certainly has a "no harm" level of impact.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable
        ( AsAt, Key1, Key2 )
SELECT u.*
FROM (
    SELECT AsAt, Key1, 130 As Key2
    FROM dbo.TestTable AS tt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AsAt, Key1, 129
    FROM dbo.TestTable AS tt
) u
```

Comment: Thanks, that's similar to the temp table solution. The question is not about how to make it work, as I have two working solutions. The question is why it behaves like that

Comment: @Juan - Understood, if your question is truly about getting to the nature of how the RDBMS planning engine works in this circumstance, you are going to have to probably go to the engineering source for a true answer. The basis of using an RDBMS and declarative syntax (and thinking) is that understanding the "how" is not profoundly necessary. But I understand your curiosity.

Comment: Well it does in this case when its doing something its not supposed to be doing :)